# using mongolab with angular for update(put) but record is not getting updated correctly

Tags: angularjs, mlab

I have the following Angular code below. I'm noticing that when I call ng-click="update($index, list.name)" to update the name field, it is creating a new key/value pair in my JSON list for ID which is not necessary. Also all my other fields such as type, CDN etc. are getting wiped out. I only want to update the name field. Thanks!

```
                    var tools = angular.module("tools", ['ngResource'])
                 tools.config(function($routeProvider) {
                    $routeProvider.when('/home', {
                        templateUrl: 'home.html',
                        controller: 'HomeController'
                    });
                    $routeProvider.when('/about', {
                        templateUrl: 'about.html',
                        controller: 'AboutController'
                    });
                    $routeProvider.otherwise({
                        redirectTo: '/home'
                    })
                });
                tools.controller("HomeController", function($scope, fetchData, containItems, fetchData) {
                    $scope.arrayofModel = ["nothing"];
                    $scope.clearSearch = function() {
                        $scope.search = "";
                        $scope.name2 = "";
                    }
                    $scope.name2 = "";
                    $scope.search = "";
                    //READ
                    $scope.record = fetchData.query();
                    //CREATE
                    $scope.addNew = function(name, $location) {
                        //Create the forum object to send to the back-end
                        var forum = new fetchData($scope.addNew1);
                        //Save the forum object
                        forum.$save(function(response) {
                            $scope.record.unshift(response);
                            //$scope.record = fetchData.query();
                        }, function(response) {
                            //Post response objects to the view
                            $scope.errors = response.data.errors;
                        });
                    }
                    //DELETE
                    $scope.destroy = function(index) {
                        //alert($scope.record[index]._id.$oid);
                        //return false;
                        //Tell the server to remove the object
                        fetchData.delete({
                            id: $scope.record[index]._id.$oid
                        }, function() {
                            //If successful, remove it from our collection
                            $scope.record.splice(index, 1);
                        });
                    }
                    //UPDATE
                    $scope.update = function(index, newName) {
                        fetchData.update({
                            id: $scope.record[index]._id.$oid,
                            name: newName
                        }, function() {
                            console.log('posted');
                            $scope.record = fetchData.query();
                        });
                    }
                });
                tools.controller("AboutController", function($scope) {});
                tools.factory('fetchData', function($resource) {
                    return $resource('https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/frameworks/collections/list/:id?s={name: 1}&apiKey=_QnS_M-Iz9-RCKJNmVYEMvvaYL', {}, {
                        'get': {
                            method: 'GET'
                        },
                        'save': {
                            method: 'POST'
                        },
                        //CREATE
                        'query': {
                            method: 'GET',
                            isArray: true
                        },
                        //READ
                        'remove': {
                            method: 'DELETE'
                        },
                        'update': {
                            method: 'PUT',
                            params: {
                                id: "@id"
                            }
                        },
                        //UPDATE
                        'delete': {
                            method: 'DELETE',
                            params: {
                                id: "@id"
                            }
                        }
                    }) //DELETE
                });
```

also here is my view:

```
 <tbody>

   <tr ng-repeat="list in record | filter: {type:name2, name: search}">
     <td>{{list._id.$oid}}</td>
     <td><input ng-model="list.name"></td>
     <td>{{list.type}}</td>
     <td><img src="{{list.logo}}" /></td>
     <td><a target="_blank" href="{{list.url}}">URL</a></td>
     <td><a ng-show="list.CDN != ''" href="{{list.CDN}}">CDN</a></td>
     <td><a target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" href="{{list.download}}" ng-click="putConsole(list.name)">Download</a></td>
     <td><a target="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" ng-click="destroy($index)">Delete!</a></td>
     <td><a target="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" ng-click="update($index, list.name)">Update!</a></td>
  </tr>
  <!--<tr><span ng-show="totalCount.length == '0'">No results found. Please reset your search and try again!</span></tr>-->
```

Comment: There is a bit of boilerplate code involved while making AngularJS working with MongLoab so you might want to a service I'm maintaining to make this task easier: https://github.com/pkozlowski-opensource/angularjs-mongolab-promise and (or the $resource based https://github.com/pkozlowski-opensource/angularjs-mongolab)

Answer (score 2):

When you perform an update with MongoDB, it will replace the existing document with the one you specify unless you use update operators:

http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/applications/update/

In your case, if you want to change the value of a single field while leaving the rest alone, you have to use the "$set" operator:

http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/applications/update/#update-a-field-in-a-document

For example:

```
{ "$set" : { "name" : newName } }
```

This should appear in the body of the PUT request.  The _id of the document you want to change should be specified in the URL.  See the "View, update, or delete a document" section in the official API documentation for more details:

https://support.mongolab.com/entries/20433053-rest-api-for-mongodb

Comment: And don't forget to JSON.stringify the data payload before sending it... I just had that issue.